# Rhythmbox exiting unexpectedly (crashing) when trying to play an audio file

Tags: 14.04, crash, rhythmbox

Ubuntu flavour: Ubuntu (Official)
Ubuntu distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

I was using Rhythmbox OK until yesterday, when the problems started.

Yesterday, I double-clicked on a song on the playlist and Rhythmbox froze there. This happened for 4 times, and I had to close it from System Monitor (`gnome-system-monitor`). However, when I clicked on the Play button, it played the first song fine, with no problems at all. But, to get to the song I wanted Rhythmbox to play, I had to click on "Next" until I got there.

Today, I started Rhythmbox. It was fine. But when I pressed on "Play", it exited automatically and no `apport` window showed up. I also checked for it in System Monitor, but there wasn't any `apport` process there.

If it is a bug in Rhythmbox, let me know so I can post it on Launchpad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bajiru

Comment: Do you happen to have the Alternative Toolbar plugin installed? That plugin is causing the same problem you described, [Bug #1770135 Rhythmbox initially crashes when trying to play a song](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1770135)

Comment: @karel No I didn't have a plugin. Perhaps Ubuntu 14.04 didn't like my PC!... Anyway, I'm now installing Kubuntu, so, I'm OK now! Thanks for your time, by the way!